# Writing a Query for adding missing columns in tables in one database from another similar database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008-r2

We have 2 databases: `QMS` and `QMS_Chennai`.

`QMS` contains these tables:

```
tbl_table1
tbl_table2
tbl_table3
```

`QMS_Chennai` contains these tables:

```
tbl_table1
tbl_table2
```

The tables in the `QMS` database contain a few columns which are not in the same tables in the `QMS_Chennai` database.

I need to check what tables are present in both databases and add the additional columns to tables in the `QMS_Chennai` database from `QMS`.

Need to write some query as we have to face this scenario number of times in case of different databases. We are using SQL Server 2008 R2

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Schmea Compare from VS 2010 will help you in this.
Link for more details.
[Schema Compare](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/145979/SQL-Server-Schema-Comparison-Tool-in-Visual-Studio)

For higher version of VS i.e VS 2012 check this [Schema Compare](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/555932/How-to-Compare-Database-Schema)

or for Vs 2013 this [Schema Compare](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/773455/Schema-Data-Comparison-of-Two-Databases-with-Visua)

Answer (score 0):

you can get the table name which are present in both table by this query:-

```
  select * from QMS .INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES as bb 
  inner join QMS_Chennai .INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES as cc
  on bb.TABLE_NAME=cc.TABLE_NAME
```